# Вывод ID из трех таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста составить правильный запрос

```
$myinfopost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE idUser='$myid'");
$myinfopost1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE idUser='$myid'");
$myinfopost2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE idus='$myid'");
   while ($myinfoposts = mysql_fetch_array($myinfopost,$myinfopost1,$myinfopost2)) {
            echo $myinfoposts[id];
   }
```

Надо одновременно из всех вывести ID

Пробовал ещё так:
но выводит только из последней таблицы (photo).

```
$myinfopost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post p, comment c, photo ph WHERE (p.idUser='$myid' AND c.idUser='$myid') AND ph.idus='$myid'");
```

**Проблему решил таким запросом:**

```
SELECT * FROM post p, comment c, photo ph, likes li WHERE ((li.post = p.id AND p.idUser = '$myid') OR (li.comment = c.id AND c.idUser = '$myid')) OR (li.photo = ph.id AND ph.idus = '$myid')
```

Comment: Задача решается довольно легко, но мне кажется, что, на самом деле, задача другая. Озвучьте, что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: Мне надо вывести ID из каждой таблицы одним разом, после чего будет подсчитываться кол-во выведенных строк и далее сам вывод этих строк уже из другой таблицы.

Comment: А если в одной таблице 5 записей, в другой 20, а в третьей 3. Что будете выводить?

Comment: Необходимо вывести всё

Comment: В зависимости от ситуации вижу 2 решения.

1) поочередно делаете запрос к базе к одной из таблиц и сразу же выводите данные из неё, т.е. примерно так: 
    $myinfopost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE idUser='$myid'");
     while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($myinfopost))
и так 3 раза по каждой таблице.

2) Сделайте один запрос к MySQL с UNION всех трёх таблиц

Comment: UNION почему то не помогает, хотя это как раз то что и надо...

Comment: А вы пишите `union all` что бы он не подавлял дубли ? И если "далее уже вывод из другой таблицы", то стоит показать еще и структуру той другой таблицы и конечную задачу, потому как всегда _можно_ (и в большинстве случаев _нужно) получить все необходимые данные одним запросом.

Comment: Вывести все без какой либо корреляции с другими запросами? Т.е. вначале выводим все `id` из первого запроса, потом из второго и из третьего. Так?

Comment: Да. Верно. Я решил эту проблему сделав большой запрос как во втором варианте.

Comment: Зачем `AND` ?  `OR` не сойдет?